# Calculate Average login time of user in past 30 days

Tags: mysql, db2

For XYZ analysis I want to calculate the Average of Login time for Users in last 30 days and put it in the table as AVG_login time.

Table_1:

```
user_id  Login_time
10000001  2021.04.12T12:30:03
10000001  2021.04.11T12:31:04
10000001  2021.04.10T12:30:01
10000001  2021.04.09T12:35:12
10000001  2021.04.08T12:25:30
10000002  2021.04.11T12:30:01
10000002  2021.04.10T12:29:08
10000002  2021.04.09T12:12:12
10000002  2021.04.08T12:34:23
10000002  2021.04.07T12:14:43
10000002  2021.04.06T12:30:19
```

table_2

```
User_id    AVG_time_login
10000001   -
10000002   -
```

Please anyone help me how to write MySql query to get “AVG_time_login” in “table_2”.

Comment: you tagged two rdbms mysql and db2.  What is the relevance to db2 ?

Comment: How can you calculate login time, you only have the time they logged in, and nothing about when they logged out. Or do you mean the average time that people logged in to the system

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest using proper date datatype for `Login_time` column.
If I understood correctly please follow below example :

```
CREATE TABLE table_1(
user_id INT,
login_time varchar(30));

insert into table_1 values
(10000001,'2021.04.12T12:30:03'),
(10000001,'2021.04.11T12:31:04'),
(10000001,'2021.04.10T12:30:01'),
(10000001,'2021.04.09T12:35:12'),
(10000001,'2021.04.08T12:25:30'),
(10000002,'2021.04.11T12:30:01'),
(10000002,'2021.04.10T12:29:08'),
(10000002,'2021.04.09T12:12:12'),
(10000002,'2021.04.08T12:34:23'),
(10000002,'2021.04.07T12:14:43'),
(10000002,'2021.04.06T12:30:19');

CREATE TABLE table_2(
user_id INT,
AVG_time_login varchar(30) );
```

First you can filter the data :

```
    SELECT user_id,
           avg(datediff(max_date,min_date)) as AVG_time_login
    FROM (
            SELECTuser_id , 
                   max(str_to_date(login_time,'%Y.%m.%dT%H:%i:%s')) as max_date ,
                   min(str_to_date(login_time,'%Y.%m.%dT%H:%i:%s')) as min_date
            FROM table_1
            GROUP BY user_id 
         ) as t1
   GROUP BY user_id;
```

Then you can insert in your table using [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
insert into table_2          ( user_id,
                              AVG_time_login
                              )
SELECT user_id,
       avg(datediff(max_date,min_date)) as AVG_time_login
FROM (
        SELECT  user_id , 
                max(str_to_date(login_time,'%Y.%m.%dT%H:%i:%s')) as max_date ,
                min(str_to_date(login_time,'%Y.%m.%dT%H:%i:%s')) as min_date
        FROM table_1
        GROUP  BY user_id 
     ) as t1
GROUP  BY user_id ;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> user_id     AVG_time_login
> 10000001  4.000000000
> 10000002  5.000000000
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea61b2ef17bd432b33e3a8fb7d724096)

Edit on comment:

```
SELECT user_id,SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC((str_to_date(login_time,'%Y.%m.%dT%H:%i:%s'))))) as AVG_time_login
FROM table_1
WHERE  str_to_date(login_time,'%Y.%m.%dT%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
group by user_id;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91fd469a77d1094baf1e8a2cf28a0d9e)

Comment: thanks for the respence and suggestions, this is sample data, I want to take average of user login on time basis for last 30 days

Comment: And Logintime datatype is TIMESTAMP, could you please suggest how to take last 30days data and avg only time from it, what I am thinking is converting to string then substring date and time to seperate column then do avg on time, can you help me, how to do that.. calculated avg time should be in time format… e.g 12:29:01

Comment: @PiyushChandra check the edit, and please post real data because ` 2021.04.12T12:30:03` is not a valid timestamp format. I select the last 30 days based on current date

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Db2:

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 (User_id, AVG_time_login)
SELECT 
  user_id
, TIME ('00:00:00') + AVG (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS (Login_time))
FROM Table_1
WHERE Login_time > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 30 DAYS
GROUP BY user_id
```